# Managing header templates?

Tags: asp.net, html, web

I'm new to  creating html pages etc - but am using VS 2008 just for the editing/intellisense capabilities.

My problem is I have a pure HTML only website (no ASP.NET) and have a fairly extensive header that has to be used in every page.  It's frustrating to change the header parts of the HTML across all pages every single time it changes in one. Is there someway I can sort of 'include' the header part HTML in other HTML pages without having to manually cut-paste all-over?

Please note - I'm not using ASP.NET, so I CANNOT and WILL NOT be able to use Master Pages. Is there some other technique is what I want to know - so that when I change the header template in 1 place, it gets reflected in all other. I thought of inline frames, but not sure if that's a crappy way to do that and if it affects SEO

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Server Side Includes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes)

They'll allow you to edit your header in the one file, which will appear instantly on all pages that include the header file.

Comment: +1 SSI is an often overlooked, but still really useful and widely available technology.

Comment: Thanks! Answers my question!. I'm using IIS for testing (on XP Pro) with .shtml extension, but nothing happens..neither on my test browser or on my host (1&1). Can't figure out what's wrong with the simple line <!--#include virtual="/buy/hdr.shtml" -->

Comment: On XP Pro - ensure Server Side Includes was installed alongside IIS (Add/Remove Windows Components > Application Server > IIS > Server Side Includes). If it is, the virtual include should work - does it error, or just not include it (i.e. visible when viewing source)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, take a look at SSI. Server side includes are a simple way to tell your web server to insert various things at various points in your HTML page.

Example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <!--#include FILE="head.html" -->   
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

If server side includes don't appear to work as expected, try renaming the page with a .shtml file extension.

Some web servers require that you name your file ".shtml" rather than ".html" in order to enable the parsing of your file.